# RegularExpressionValidator for TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I had a question on here for a RegularExpressionValidator which I'm relatively new to. It was to accept all alphanumeric, apostrophe, hyphen, underscore, space, ampersand, comma, parentheses, full stop.

The answer I was given was:

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9 '-_&,()\.])+$"
```

This seemed good at first but it seems to accept amoung other things '*'.

Can anybody tell me what I have wrong here?

Comment: Is that really what you used? You're missing a close-parens ) somewhere (there's an opening one at the start, no close)

Comment: Typed it wrong. I've edited it now and that's what I have. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't wrap the example in "" when youre giving an example where every character has a special meaning. its not clear to us whether you are using this in your real validator or not. I'm assuming not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the dash - inside a character class, if unescaped and not at the very end or very beginning of the character class, it denotes a range (`A-Z` would be a good example from your own regex).

Therefore `'-_` is also interpreted as a range, and the characters between ASCII 39 (`'`) and ASCII 95 (`_`) are `()*+,-./0-9:;<=>?@A-Z[\]^`.

Put the dash at the end, and you should be fine:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 '_&,().-]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your character class is not quite correct. This part: `'-_` creates a range from the apostrophe character to the underscore character. In the ASCII table, the `*` character falls in between. You need to either escape the hyphen:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 '\-_&,()\.])+$
```

Or move it somewhere "insignificant", such as the end of the character class:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 '_&,()\.-])+$
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the '-_ issue touched on by other people you also have the + on the end in the wrong place.

The value capture group in this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 '-_&,()\.])+$
```

in Expresso is the last character in the string.

If you want to capture the whole thing inside the regex then put the + straight after the ] like

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 '-_&,()\.]+)$
```

If you are not bothered about extracting the value captured inside the ( ) then drop the ()

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 '-_&,()\.]+$
```

Comment: +1. Since this is for a Validator, and Validators have no use for capturing groups, those parentheses serve no purpose at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I also tripped up on the fact that this uses a character class in my initial answer, I dug around for more info.  Found the following tutorial excerpt at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

> The only special characters or
>   metacharacters inside a character
>   class are the closing bracket (]), the
>   backslash (), the caret (^) and the
>   hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters
>   are normal characters inside a
>   character class, and do not need to be
>   escaped by a backslash.

Escaping the `-` with `\-` should solve your problem.

Comment: Not even when in a character class?

Comment: I'm not sure what the edit was? Either was I should have had \.

Comment: @Paul  You are correct.  I assumed since he was looking for a period and was getting other characters it would have been a good place to look.

Comment: @BigJim  It was the `\.` You can see the edits by clicking on the timer beside the "edited" line of the question.